# How to create general media player in Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I want to a media player can play image, audio video based on the source from url in SL app.
How to implement it in SL?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [Silverlight Media Framework](http://smf.codeplex.com/)

It provides out of the box ful and roboust media player experience.

If you just want to play a video use the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980132%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)